# React Native function bind parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to render a list which calls a function to render the rows, but how can I pass the paramater data to the function/handler?
The data is in json style.

I tried many things but I always get an error back, what am I doing wrong?

This the code:

```html
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://link/json.php', {
     method: 'GET'
   })
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
     dataJson = responseJson;
        this.setState({
          preLoad: true
        });
      })
    .catch((error) => {

   });
  }


  renderRows(item){
    if(item.type == 2){
      return(
        <ListItem>
        <Thumbnail square size={80} source={{ uri: 'item.image' }} />
        <Body>
        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
        <Text note>{item.desc}</Text>
        </Body>
        </ListItem>
      )
    }
  }


  renderMenu(){

    if(this.state.preLoad){

      return(
       <List dataArray={dataJson}
       renderRow={(item) =>
         this.renderRows().bind(this,item)
       }>
       </List>
       )

    }else{

      return(
        <Body>{shimmerRows}</Body>
        )
    }

  }


  render() {
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
      {this.renderMenu()}
      </Container>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just need to save your response to the state.

```
this.setState({
  preLoad: true,
  dataJson: responseJson,
});
```

And do the binding correctly.

```
<List dataArray={this.state.dataJson}
   renderRow={(item) => this.renderRows.bind(this,item)}>
</List>
```